# Resetting Angular input by creating new object vs reassigning properties

Tags: angularjs

Why do the three commented out lines not work? Although they do reset the input fields to empty, the output is also completely empty. only by reassigning to an object does it work correctly. (leaving out my factory file for Users.create for brevity, it performs an http get)

It seems in both cases "bro" gets logged before "hey", my guess is that the 3 lines are reassigning $scope.newUser before it goes into User.create,.. but  wouldn't $scope.newUser = {} do that as well?

```
  $scope.addUser = function (){
    Users.create($scope.newUser).then(function() {
      // console.log('hey');
      $scope.displayUsers();
    })

    $scope.newUser = {};
    console.log('bro');
    // $scope.newUser.name = '';
    // $scope.newUser.email = '';
    // $scope.newUser.id = '';``
  };
```

Relevant HTML

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
  <h1>Testing</h1>

  <form ng-submit="addUser()">
    <input ng-model="newUser.name" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input ng-model="newUser.email" placeholder="Email">
    <input ng-model="newUser.id" placeholder="Id">
    <input type="submit" value="Add User"/>
  </form>

  <!-- <button ng-click="addUser()">Add User</button> -->
  <button ng-click="displayUsers()">View current Users</button>      

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users track by $index" ng-click="removeUser()">
      Name: {{ user.name }}  <br>Email: {{user.email}} <br> Id: {{user.id}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I understand now that you have to put those 3 lines due to async nature of javascript inside the then callback, but why don't you need to do the same thing with $scope.newUser = {}?

Comment: This is async behaviour of javascript. User.create returns a promise that gets fulfilled (then method called) sometime in future. You cannot treat it as sequential code. Move the clearing code inside the then callback.

Comment: But why does  $scope.newUser = {} work even if it's not inside the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Chandermani said, this is the classic async issue we all run into at first. Angular's methods in `$http` and `$resource` return promises, which will be fullfilled or rejected sometimes in the future. Also, when dealing with promises, remember to always handle errors with `catch`.

```
$scope.addUser = function () {
  Users.create($scope.newUser).then(function () {
    console.log('Second!');
    $scope.newUser = {};
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Something wrong happened!');
  });

  console.log('First!');
};
```

Comment: My question now is why you don't need to have the $scope.newUser inside the then callback, and it still works for some reason. $scope.newUser = {} can be outside the callback.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this is because you are creating a new object and the factory gets to keep a reference to the previous object (the new user with data), while resetting each property manually also mutates the reference used in the factory, thus creating an empty user.

Comment: Interesting... that is starting to make sense, Thanks!